# Python BeautifulSoup find with data-reactid

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape some stock prices from Yahoo Finance, but instead of getting the wanted result, 229.30, I get "Mail". Anyone know why?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

code = input("Enter the NYSE stock symbol: ")

#Your Choice Stock
source = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+ code +'/history p='+ code).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
price = soup.find('span', attrs={"data-reactid": "55"}
print(code + " stock: " + price.text)
```

Also, ignore all the other imports, they are part of my bigger file.

**EDIT**: Now it's at least giving me a number, but that number is not the one that I am looking for. It gives me 231.12, not 229.30. Also, the stock that I am getting is Costco's. (COST is the NYSE stock symbol)

**ANOTHER EDIT**: For some reason, it was reading 57 as the data-reactid, not 55. I tried using 53, and it gave me the value of 55. Why is it looking 2 data-reactids ahead?

Answer (score 3):

i try to access the url which show in the code, then i was redirected to `https://finance.yahoo.com/lookup?s=COSTCO`. I checked the element inside table and found your tag is wrong. Change `span` to `td`, everything go well

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

code = "Costco" #input("Enter the NYSE stock symbol: ")

#Your Choice Stock
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/lookup?s={}".format(code)
print(url)
source = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
symbol = soup.find('td', attrs={"data-reactid": "57"}) # 57+8*n
name = soup.find('td', attrs={"data-reactid": "58"}) # 58+8*n
price = soup.find('td', attrs={"data-reactid": "59"}) # 59+8*n
print(code + " stock: " + price.text)

print(pd.read_html(url))
```

Output:

```
https://finance.yahoo.com/lookup?s=Costco
Costco stock: 231.02
[       Symbol                             Name   ...       Type Exchange
0        COST     Costco Wholesale Corporation   ...     Stocks      NMS
1     COST.MX            COSTCO WHOLESALE CORP   ...     Stocks      MEX
2      CTO.DU         COSTCO WHOLESALE DL-,005   ...     Stocks      DUS
3      CTO.SG  COSTCO WHOLESALE CORP. Register   ...     Stocks      STU
4      CTO.MU         COSTCO WHOLESALE DL-,005   ...     Stocks      MUN
5     COST.VI            COSTCO WHOLESALE CORP   ...     Stocks      VIE
6      CTO.HM         COSTCO WHOLESALE DL-,005   ...     Stocks      HAM
7      CTO.BE         COSTCO WHOLESALE DL-,005   ...     Stocks      BER
8       CTO.F         COSTCO WHOLESALE DL-,005   ...     Stocks      FRA
9      0I47.L  COSTCO WHOLESALE CORP COSTCO WH   ...     Stocks      LSE
10  COWC34.SA                 COSTCO WHOLESALE   ...     Stocks      SAO

[11 rows x 6 columns]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`data-reactid` is dynamic for latest price it easier to get data from table date history column 5 `close*`

```
price = soup.select('table td')
print(code + " stock: " + price[4].text)
```

if you view page source there are interesting data in Json format

```
root.App.main = {..}
```

after parse select it

```
price = jsonData["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["QuoteSummaryStore"]["price"]["regularMarketPrice"]["raw"]
```